# check for duplicate value in text file/array with php

Tags: php, arrays, duplicates

If there is a file student.txt containing students record as following(first, last name, student ID) like:

```
   John Smith 2320
   Mary McHugh 4572
   Sara Britny 2322
```

I wanna check to see if the student ID is unique. if there are duplicated IDs display aan error message with the dupicated ID.

Comment: do u want to remove duplicates silently??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$ids = array();
$users = fopen("ciccio.txt", "r"); //open file
while (!feof($users)) {
    $line = fgets($users, 4096); //read one line
    list ($firstname, $lastname, $id) = explode(" ", $line);
    $id = (int)$id;
    if (empty($ids)) {
        $ids[] = $id;
    } else {
        if (in_array($id, $ids)) {
            echo "Duplicate ID: " . $id . "<br/>";
        } else {
            $ids[] = $id;
        }
    }
}
fclose($users); #close file
```

Comment: Warning: in_array() [function.in-array]: Wrong datatype for second argument in C:\AppServ\www\hw\sort11.php on line 8

Comment: the browser don't give me any output!! do you know why?

Answer (score 1):

```
arrayWithId = array
FOR EACH record AS rec IN file
   IF arrayWithId NOT CONTAINS rec THEN
      ADD rec TO arrayWithId
   ELSE
      display error
END FOR
# if you get here without any errors displayed there are no duplicates
```

Answer (score 0):

Just read the file line by line and save all ids. If one id is already saved throw an error.

```
$line = /* ... */
$data = explode( ", ", $line );

// should contain the id
$id = $data[2];
```

Comment: i used: $fh = fopen("students.txt", 'r');

while (!feof($fh))
{
 $Data = fgets($fh);
 list($array["first"], $array["last"],$array["id"]) = explode(" ",$Data);
 $a = ($array["first"], $array["last"],$array["id"]);
 $newarray[] = $a;
},,,, to read and store the data in array

Comment: I created this code to read but how to save, and if one ID is already saved throw error?

Comment: Just save the id in an array. Then you can check if $array[ $id ] is already set.

Comment: Code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7711829/check-if-the-value-in-array-is-unique-or-duplicated-php/7711963#7711963

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$file = "student.txt";
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($file));
fclose($handle);

$list = array();

$list = explode("\n",$contents);
$list = array_map("trim", $list);

$current = "foo@bar.com";

echo in_array($current,$list) ? $current.' exists' : $current.' does not exist';
?>
```

Comment: I think you should know about the [`file` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the input array, get the ID per item, if the ID is new, store the ID, if not, give error:

```
$filename = 'students.txt';

$array = file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

$unique = array();
foreach($array as $line => $student)
{
    $r = preg_match('/ (\d+)$/', $student, $matches);
    if (!$r) continue;
    list(,$id) = $matches;
    if (isset($unique[$id]))
        printf("Duplicate ID found (%d) in '%s' line %d.\n", $id, $student, $line);
    else
        $unique[$id] = 1;
}
```